# Bootstrap Lumen theme's NavBar issue

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have included bootstrap's lumen theme in my ASP.NET MVC project and replaced it with the default bootstrap.css theme. Now the issue I'm facing is that the navbar of the theme doesn't look like it should be. In fact there's no navbar at all.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace vidly
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap-Lumenn.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this image for code:

[click on this image for inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwhjE.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwhjE.png)

Hi,
Right click on header choose inspect element.
Check Yellow colored code is showing in your HTML.
Or check if CSS overwriting is happening or not

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. According to my investigation, since recording of the tutorial which you are using, the lumen theme code has changed. In the result some of the classes names has changed. 
I did not have a time to compare the source css code of bootstrap-lumen.css file used in the tutorial by the Author with the actual file available on bootswatch. So I decided to solve this quick...

This is how I solved this problem

1) go to the GitHub of the Author of the tutorial (I should not advertise him and quote his URL address but if you type his full name and add word "GitHub" you will find it.

2) choose the repository reflecting the project you are creating

3) look at the commits in this project and go to the second oldest commit

4) search for the Folder and file called ../Content/bootstrap-lumen.css

5) copy the source code of the file bootstrap-lumen.css

6) paste the source code in place of your actual source code of your local file with the same name

7) save the local file (Ctrl+S) and refresh the browser

It worked for me. I hope It helps even if its not the smartest way possible.